# Check for a 'unique_together' in a conditional sentence

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have one view that take the values from one model and then in a conditional sentence check if a specific value exist to do something, like this:

```
def MyView(request):
users = User.objects.filter().values_list('first_name', flat=True)
    if not 'Jhon' in users:
        Do something
```

That works if only take the value of one field `first_name` but **How can I do the same** with a model that use two fields as one whit the `unque_together` something like:

```
def MyViewTwo(request):
varlist = MyModel.objects.filter().values_list('fieldone','fieldtwo', flat=True)
    if not 'ValueFromFieldOneAndTwo' in varlist:
        Do something
```

The `fieldone` and `fieldtwo` are the fields in the `unique_together` `unique_together = ('fieldone','fieldtwo')`.

Comment: What you need to know is if the pair is in the list?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
def MyViewTwo(request):
    # note you shouldn't use flat=true here
    varlist = MyModel.objects.filter().values_list('fieldone','fieldtwo')
    if not (fieldonevalue, fieldtwovalue) in varlist:
        # Do something
```